# Postmaster - can't see collectionVariables in Script2

Tags: postman

the idea is, in script #1 Pre-request to copy data from the Body and then re-use it in the Script #2.
I have Collection1 and inside Folder1 and inside Script1 and Script2. In my code i can see copied data in Pre-Requst / Test of Script1 but can't see it in the Script2.

To do this, next was added in Pre-request of
in Folder1
`pm.collectionVariables.set("v_requestNum");`
In Script1 -
`var jsonReq = JSON.parse(pm.request.body);` 
`v_requestNum = jsonReq.requestNum;` 
`console.log(v_requestNum); ( it show expected '11' )`
In Script2 :
`console.log(pm.collectionVariables.get("v_requestNum")); - show 'null'`
OR
`console.log(pm.collectionVariables.get("v_requestId")); - show 'null'`
OR console.log(v_requestNum);  show next error -> ReferenceError: v_requestNum is not defined.`

Please advise how can i get v_requestNum in Script2